# Where could I ask the question "What is the cheapest stock you could buy on the US stock market"?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

This question is potentially related to coding since you could use the exchange API in any supported programming language to find out the answer.

So is it acceptable to ask this question on Stack Overflow?

If not, is there any related site where I could ask this?

Comment: Definitely not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should ask site recommendations over at [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) along with the matching tag

Comment: Anyway you should probably just ask Google that...

Comment: A broker's office.

Comment: "since you could use exchange api" Lots of things can be queried via an API, or even just crawled from the web. One might ask well as for an estimate of the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow by that logic.

Comment: "*This question is potentially related to coding since you could use exchange api in any support programming language to find out the answer.*" that doesn't make it at all programming related. I can use my phone to call my parents. That doesn't mean that the phone repair shop is in any way like my family.

Comment: It's only related to programming if you are *already* using an API and are having problems with the code you've written with it. For this, see related [Is there is any Stack Exchange community for stock market?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298882/756727)

Comment: As others have said, this isn’t a question for SO. I’d argue it’s not a question for *anywhere* on the network unless you demonstrate you’ve done your own research first. If you did that, you’d learn that the answer would be disappointing and pointless; plenty of pink sheet stocks trade for literally fractions of a cent (*because* they’re worthless), and which one is cheapest changes day by day and moment to moment, not least because these worthless stocks delist as the companies go out of business or are revealed as scams….

Comment: I wonder why everyone is answering this question in the comments, rather than in the answer box??

Comment: @MisterMiyagi african or european swallow?

Comment: @BillTür: you and Mister Miyagi are now venturing into *my* turf

Comment: I don't know much about the stock market, but I do know one thing. What is the cheapest stock is going to change in the moment, so any answer to that effect is going to be outdated/wrong almost the moment it is posted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Funny. I thought you were more a Java person than Python.

Comment: @user4581301 Check their [profile picture](https://montypython.fandom.com/wiki/Tim_the_Enchanter)... :P

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Pictures can be faked. I inspected the question and answer history. Significantly more interaction with Java questions than Python questions.

Comment: @user4581301 Hovercraft's picture is of a character from the same movie where the "African or European swallow" joke comes from - *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*. Moreover, the "hovercraft full of eels" is another callback to [a Monty Python sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1Sw0PDgHU4). The remark "my turf" wasn't about programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is the cheapest stock you could buy on the US stock market?

No, that's not a programming question, and it isn't on-topic. To spice it up towards on-topicness:

> I want to write a program that can find out the cheapest stock available on the US stock market.

Still a long way from being on-topic. It's not specific, it doesn't list your problems, where should we start, digesting Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?

You need to break down your problem into actionable components. I would start by investigating the exchanges that operate on the US stock market, especially in the "penny stock" products, as those are bound to be cheap. You search the web a bit, come across the term "micro cap" and poof, there are lists of like 10 commonly used brokers who deal in those.

So you start investigating in which stocks they deal, and after you've picked one that appears about right and offers an API, you're in programming territory.

You start to find a pre-baked API client for that broker, or if it doesn't exist for your favorite programming language, you whip up one by yourself. After all, an HTTP client and a line or two to authenticate your client against that broker's API is trivial to find out.

Then you interpret the results from that API and you're golden.

Now if you get compiler errors while trying to build your own client, package manager errors while trying to install packages, runtime errors because your HTTP call is invalid or any other actual programming error, sure, research it and then ask a question if you can't figure it out.

But by the time you're at this point, the fact that you're trying to find the cheapest stock on the US market is not relevant, like, at all.

So no, the first sentence of this answer is not a valid programming question.